# Command line equivalent of javac ant task?

Tags: java, ant

```
<javac srcdir="${src}"
         destdir="${build}"
         classpath="xyz.jar"  
         debug="on"    
         source="1.4"
/>
```

What command should I execute on the command line to get the same effect as the above code.
This code is copied from an ant build file.

Comment: `javac -help` explains it, short and sweet.

Comment: Have a look at the [JAVAC documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html). If that does not help, be more specific on what's not working. Btw, remember to first think, then google/bing, and then ask.

Comment: Try: `javac -cp xyz.jar -source 1.4 -d /path/to/build -verbose /path/to/src/*.java`

Answer (score 3):

Invoke ant with the `-v` flag for verbose and it should output the exact command send to `javac`.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the [`Command-Line options`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html) for Ant.

Comment: I don't want to use ant at all.. I am currently compiling with ant but want to move away completely.. Ant must be using javac <with some command line options> for the above code.. right??